# Ansible lookup env with $ and inject into jj2 template not working

Tags: ansible, devops, gitlab-ci

We're using Ansible playbook with GitLab CI in this project, where we'd pass some variables from ENV_FILE through Ansible playbook, then rendering JJ2 template with them.

Now the problem occurs when some variable has `$` in its value, which seems interpreted as shell variable at some point, and the final value is rendered incorrect.

For example, in *ENV_FILE*
(set via GitLab CI Settings > CI/CD > Variables menu):

```
export FIRST_VAR=...
export SOME_VAR='123$abc@xyz'
export SOME_OTHER_VAR=...
```

And the final result in docker-compose.yaml becomes `123@xyz`

*EDIT*: We just tried changing to `export SOME_VAR='123''$''abc@xyz'`, the final result becomes `123abc@xyz`, still missing the `$`.

*gitlab-ci.yaml*

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment: 
    name: dev
  script: 
    - source $ENV_FILE
    - cd ansible && ansible-playbook -i inventory/dev.ini runapp.yaml --vault-password-file=${ANSIBLE_VAULT_FILE}
```

*runapp.yaml*

```yaml
- hosts: app
  become: yes
  roles:
    - { role: some_app }
  vars:
    SOME_VAR: "{{ lookup('env', 'SOME_VAR') }}"
```

Task File:

```yaml
- name: "Templating docker-compose file"
  become: yes
  template:
    src: app-docker-compose.yaml.j2
    dest: /opt/someapp/docker-compose.yaml
```

*app-docker-compose.yaml.j2*

```
  someapp-svc:
    image: someapp:version
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ####:####
    environment:
      SOME_VAR: {{ SOME_VAR }}
```

Any hint about this?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with ansible nor gitlab-ci. This is a pure shell var definition problem. Simply quote your value correctly in your env file with simple quotes. `SOME_VAR=123$abc@xyz; echo $SOME_VAR` => 123@xyz (unless you defined variable `abc`). `SOME_VAR='123$abc@xyz'; echo $SOME_VAR` => 123$abc@xyz

Comment: @Zeitounator We've already quoted it, in GitLab CI/CD Vars ENV_FILE:
`export SOME_VAR='123$abc@xyz'`
Maybe I'd try echoing the var in pipeline.

Comment: Note that you did not provide `ENV_FILE` and that your example var assignment does not use `export` and is not quoted. You should update your question.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6f277165ba042d8348ca2a3f206c2146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce that behavior when setting a CI/CD variable containing `$`; [the docs kind of hint at it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#gitlab-ciyml-defined-variables), although the docs are written as if the problem only applies when setting variables inside `.gitlab-ci.yml` which is demonstrably false

If you want a CI/CD variable to contain a literal `$`, it needs to be doubled, so `SOME_VAR` would need to be written as `123$$abc@xyz` in the CI/CD configuration page in order for it to materialize as `123$abc@xyz` inside the pipeline *(although as the comments correctly point out, one will want to be exceedingly careful about the use of `source` to avoid further interpolation)*